# iOS 13 Scrolling issue with blob pdf files (no scrolling with one finger)

Tags: ios, pdf, scroll, blob, filesaver.js

My application opens a pdf from a blob object, since the update to iOS 13, the newly opened pdf does not scroll with one finger.
Using two fingers make the scrolling work.

Tested on iphone with iOS 12.x, and it indeed scrolls with one finger.

The only 'good' change is the title of the pdf viewer that changes from 'blob' (in iOS 12.x) to the regular domain in iOS 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed in the iOS 13.1 update!